# How to make a div as wide as its sibling but not wider?

Tags: css, width

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="label">
    foor bar baz
  </div>
  <img src="...">
</div>
```

Yes, I know that div with class "label" should be a label.

The simple question is: how do I ensure that the label is always exactly as wide as the picture and never wider?
The width of the picture and the content of the label are unknown. When the content of the label is longer than the width of the image, it should break to the next line.

Right now, I have "display: inline-block" for the wrapper and everything looks fine when the text fits in the label. When the text is longer, it doesn't break, though, but makes the label longer than the image.

I guess there's a simple solution for this but I'm just not seeing it.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: It should only be a label element if it labels a form control.

Comment: I think this is not a proper answer so I'm putting it here: I think any width in percentage unit inherits the father div width, so if you put label width 100% it will be as wide as the father div. This has problems though, so use 99%.

Comment: @Oscar That would only work if the father div (wrapper) had a specified width. If it hasn't and I set the label div's width to 100%, it stays the same size as if I hadn't set the width at all. (Setting the width to 90% makes it 10% smaller etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an element can't be larger than it's parent so if you put the img tag inside the div it will never be larger.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="label">
    foor bar baz
    <img src="...">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, of course that is correct. I'll kick the label div completely and just keep everything in the wrapper. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give both elements a `width:50%;` (or width:49%;, just to be safe) attribute, that should do the trick.

Comment: I don't really understand. Which "both" elements do you mean? As I said, the width of the picture is unknown and I don't want to change it.

Comment: I think the OP is assuming you want to divide the top-level div into even left and right sections, rather than above and below sections.

Comment: (And seeing '49% to be safer' makes me want to hurt the people who wrote IE and screwed with the minds of a generation of webdesigners.)